# C# - Static class call means "content at address ? "

Tags: c#

Just i have a bit of confusion in understanding static reference.

incase of instance reference we can understand when i declare

```
Car myCar = new Car();

Car yourCar = new Car();

---------------                       --------------
stack                                 Managed Heap
----------------                      --------------
                                        -----
myCar         ------- > points to       Car
                                        -----
YourCar       ------- > points to       Car
                                        -----

-----------------                     ---------------
```

What if the case of  Static class ? can i mean it when i declare

```
staticClass.MyMethod( )

-----------------
Managed Heap
----------------
staticClass
(Memory Address ) 
-----------------
```

Update: Since class is blueprint and objects are physical entities;Incase of static class when i declare staticClass.MyMethod or staticClass.MyField = value ,am i directly interacting with heap ?(As no instance is allowed for static class).

Comment: Anything else you're after? You unaccepted my answer, so presumably you still have some doubts... :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `static` in C# basically means "related to the type rather than an instance of the type".

Any static method is resolved statically - i.e. at compile time - so calling

```
StaticClass.MyMethod()
```

just resolves to a call to the static method, with no instance involved at all. There's nothing to point to, other than the type itself (which is sort of done implicitly).

Note that you're not allowed to declare a variable of a type which is a static class.

EDIT: Basically, the difference here is between a static method and an instance method. It so happens that static classes can't have instance methods, and you can't create instance methods, but there's no difference between:

```
StaticClass.StaticMethod();
```

and

```
NormalClass.StaticMethod();
```

and even

```
SomeValueType.StaticMethod();
```

EDIT: To respond to your edit:

- When you set a static field, that does indeed affect the heap, but I believe it's a slightly different area of heap memory than the normal gen0/gen1/gen2 heap. (I think there's on heap per `AppDomain` for static variables, basically.)
- When you call a static method, that's basically going to end up in the JITted code as a call to a bit of code at a particular address. In other words, it'll be in some executable piece of memory, but not in the area of memory used for instance data.

EDIT: I'm not sure what you mean by "application level scope" - but a static variable is associated with the type, which is associated with the `AppDomain`. The variable will be preserved as long as the `AppDomain` is loaded. It could be unloaded for various reasons.

Comment: Yes.I know i can not declare a variable of a type which is a static class. My intention is how is it internally represented in heap.

Comment: Jon i have updated my question.I am sorry not framing what exactly i want.

Comment: :) Yes i get what i wanted exactly,somebody deleted my update.Anyhow i got the answer.

Comment: As static is in the scope of application level, when the memory is alloted in some piece of executable what happen when that thead aborted ? won't we lose application level scope variable ?

Comment: Edited to respond to comment.

Comment: Your answer is  10000000000000000000000%  accepted. Unfortunately due to mouse problem (instead of clicking on vote ; i clicked on unaccepted answer)  and power off too, so i was unable to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

Think of static classes as a namespace for related methods. It's technically no Object-Oriented programming since the class won't be used to create objects. It's just a way to combine related methods together and allowing some OO related techniques to be applied to the class. (Inheritance, most of all.)